# Smooth vertical page scrolling using mouse wheel and scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, mousewheel, parallax

I am playing around and trying to build a parallax website - yes, I know they are an annoying fad but I would still like to have a go.  So, for inspiration, I have been looking at various examples of good parallax websites and came across this one: https://victoriabeckham.landrover.com/INT.

It has smooth scrolling using the mouse wheel, scrollbar, and anchor links. I have been searching for jQuery plugins that would achieve this effect but can only seem to find ones that use internal page links - anchor or ID's (detailed below) -  but, not mouse wheel and scrollbar. There is a good chance that I am searching using the wrong keywords. Does anyone know the correct terminology to find these plugins or know any plugins that would achieve this effect?

On a side note, I am currently learning jQuery and Javascript but am in the very early stages - still trawling through codeacademy and not made it onto any real world code yet. So at the moment I am playing with plugins as a way of learning but hopefully in a few months I can build my own stuff!

Smooth scrolling to anchor tags or ID's:

- http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo
- http://jsfiddle.net/9Amdx/7/
- http://arthurclemens.github.com/jquery-page-scroll-plugin/
- http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/09/animated-scrolling-with-jquery-12
- http://www.designova.net/scrollerbird/
- http://chris-spittles.co.uk/?p=462
- http://joelb.me/scrollpath/ (*courtesy of @DrunkRocketeer)

And, another example of a parallax website using a similar technique for scrolling:

- http://www.ascensionlatorre.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one. https://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/

It has got

```
$().scrollTop()
```

jQuery event listener too so you can have scroll path configured with parallax script.

Comment: That looks perfect, many thanks. Will go and give it a quick try. This is why I love stackoverflow! *Edit: Works like a dream :)

Comment: Link is not working "Error establishing a database connection"

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to combine several of these effects in order to make something that resembles  the Landrover site. A Smooth scroll script, a scroll path script and a parallax script.

This is an interesting site for the path element of that website:
http://joelb.me/scrollpath/

Though the best way to find out how these sites work is to examine them! Some cool sites useing parallax:
http://www.awwwards.com/?s=parallax&post_type=all&search=Ok

I hope this was of some help/inspiration!

Comment: Thanks, for the info - http://joelb.me/scrollpath/ is new to me, looks perfect for parallax sites. I think your right about having combine scripts to achieve the smooth scrolling - I was inspecting their code and it looked like they might have a couple of things combined, but sadly way beyond my knowledge of js and jQuery.